# Can someone explain the following Scheme code?

Tags: scheme

I have been listening to Stanford's [programming paradigm lecture series](http://see.stanford.edu/see/lecturelist.aspx?coll=2d712634-2bf1-4b55-9a3a-ca9d470755ee), but I'm confused by the following code (from lecture 20). Would someone explain, line by line, what this is doing?

Thanks.

```
(define (flatten sequence)
  (cond ((null? sequence) '())
        ((list? (car sequence)) (append (flatten (car sequence))
                                        (flatten (cdr sequence))))
        (else (cons (car sequence)
                    (flatten (cdr sequence))))))
```

Comment: I miss Scheme from my college days

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
# define a procedure 'flatten' that takes a list 'sequence'
(define (flatten sequence)
  # if the 'sequence' is empty, return an empty list
  (cond ((null? sequence) (list))
        # if the first element of 'sequence' is itself a list, return a new list
        # made by appending the flattened first element of 'sequence' with the
        # flattened rest of the 'sequence'
        ((list? (car sequence))
         (append (flatten (car sequence))
                 (flatten (cdr sequence))))
        # if the first element of 'sequence' is not a list, return a new list
        # made by cons-ing that element with the flattened rest of the 'sequence'
        (else
         (cons (car sequence)
               (flatten (cdr sequence))))))
```

I pretty-printed it (inserted some newlines and indented the code to show its structure) and also replaced `'()` with `(list)` (which has the same value) just to prevent the code from being highlighted incorrectly.

> +1 what is cons-ing? I'd appreciate if you explain other keywords as well. thanks

When I say cons-ing I'm just referring to the `cons` procedure. When you see `(cons <expression> <list>)` where *`<expression>`* is any Scheme expression or value and *`<list>`* is any Scheme expression that evaluates to a list, `cons` will return the *`<list>`* with the value of the *`<expression>`* tacked on the front of it. For example, `(cons 1 (list 2 3 4))` returns the list `(list 1 2 3 4)`. In fact, `(list 1 2 3 4)` in Scheme is just a short way of writing `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 '() ))))`.

The other two words you might have trouble with are `car` and `cdr`. You can think of `(car <list>)` as meaning the *first* element or *head* of the *`<list>`*, and `(cdr <list>)` as meaning the *rest* of the elements or *tail* of the *`<list>`*. For example, `(car (list 1 2 3 4))` returns the value `1`, and `(cdr (list 1 2 3 4))` returns the list `(list 2 3 4)`.

If you need any help with other keywords, let me know.

Comment: oh, just remembered scheme comments start with semi-colons. but when I change the octothorpes to semi-colons the highlighting gets messed up...

Comment: +1 what is cons-ing? I'd appreciate if you explain other keywords as well. thanks

Comment: thanks @Jeremy Ruten -- you seem to know your way around scheme!

Answer (score 1):

1. define function to flatten a
   sequence
2. For the empty sequence, return empty
3. if the head (car) of the list is a
   sequence return the result of
   flattening it appended to the
   flattening of the tail (cdr)
4. else append the head to the flatting
   of the tail